# Constructing (irreducible) polynomial of odd degree with exactly two non-real roots

Tags: galois-theory, radical-equations

I am trying to understand construction of irreducible polynomial of odd  degree over $\mathbb{Q}$ with exactly two non-real roots. Let $g(x)=(x^2+m)(x-n_1)\cdots (x-n_{k-2})$ with $m>0$, $n_1< \cdots < n_{k-2}$ and  $k\ge 3$ odd.

(1) $n_1$ being simple simple root, $g'(n_1)\neq 0$, so in small  neighbourhood of $n_1$, $g$ is either *strictly* increasing or  decreasing. Assume first case is there [so from $n_1$ toward right, in small neighbourhood, $g$ is increasing.]

(2) If $g$ is strictly *increasing* in neighbourhood of $n_2$, then it is situation of Fig. 1 below. This will force $g$ to have one more root between $n_1$ and $n_2$. This is contradiction to the choice of $g$. [So Fig. 1 is impossible]

(3) **Conclusion:** If $g$ is *strictly increasing* in small neighbourhood of $n_1$ then it is *strictly decreasing* in small neighbourhood of next simple root $n_2$.  So it is in Fig. 2. Moreover (this justification says that) if in $(n_1,n_2)$, $g$ has a relative maxima, then in next interval $(n_2,n_3)$ it must have a relative minima.

> **Q.** Is it necessary that relative maxima/minima for $g$ above in any interval above is unique?

**Partial answer:** We can say that Fig. 3 and Fig. 4 should not occur. Suppose  Fig. 3 is possibility. Notice that in $(n_1,n_2)$, $g'(x)$ has three zeros. [A point $a$ is local maxima or minima implies $g'(a)=0$].

If $a$ is local maxima/ minima, call it *local extrema*. We've $k-3$ intervals $(n_i,n_{i+1})$ for ($1\le i\le k-3$).

Then, the total extremas for $(k-3)$ intervals is  $\ge (3) + (3) + (1+\cdots + 1) $ [with $1$ appearing $k-5$ times]. This is $k+1$, which is $>\deg(g'(x))$, contradiction. Similarly Fig. 4 is not possible.

So my question is about, precisely: In only one interval, say $(n_1,n_2)$ can $g$ have exactly three extrema?

**Ref.** Jacobson's Basic Algebra Vol. 1 (p. 269).

[image]

Comment: As you're quoting the book, it's worth noting that $m$ and $n_i$ are integers (even *even* integers) there.

Comment: You may find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/130088/11619) very interesting.

Comment: [Another closely related thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1245490/11619).

Comment: @Metamorphy: I am using that book, but for the problems, I am considering minimal hypothesis of its (so above description does not use at all the hypothesis about $m$ and $n_i$'s. It may be required some later stage.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the extrema to be unique, $f(x)=g'(x)/g(x)$ must have unique zeros, so
$$-f'(x)=2\frac{x^2-m}{(x^2+m)^2}+\sum_{i=1}^{k-2}\frac{1}{(x-n_i)^2}$$
must *not* have zeros in these intervals.

This is violated if $n_1<0<n_2$, $m$ is small and $|n_i|$ are large. (Actually, $g(x)=(x^2+1)(x+2)(x-2)(x-3)$ is already a counterexample.)